# Create Associative Array inside a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Hi I've created an array with a for loop inside. The array doesn't have any data inside it until it reaches the for loop. I wanted to add an associative array to what I've done so far. For example my array currently ouputs

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Version 5
            [1] => Feb-16
            [2] => gary
            [3] => 80
            [4] => P
        )
```

I would like it to have headings instead of numbers

```
[0] => Array
        (
            Version => Version 5
            Date => Feb-16
            Name => gary
            RandNum => 80
            Letter => P
        }
```

I'm not sure how i'd fit into my loop and how I could if my different columns these headings. Below is my current code. Which outputs the array at the top.

```
 for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){

      for($j = 0; $j <= 4; $j++){

           if ($j == 0){
                $times_table[$i][$j]=  "Version 5" ;
           }
           else if ($j == 1){
                $cur_date = date("M-y", $currentdate);

                $currentdate = strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate);

                $times_table[$i][$j]= "<strong>" . $cur_date . "</strong>" ;
           }
           else{
                    $times_table[$i][$j]=  "gary" ;
           }
           if ($j == 3) {
                    $numbers = mt_rand(1, 100);
                    $times_table[$i][$j]= $numbers ;

           }
           if ($j == 4){

                    if($i == 0 || $i == 3)
                    {
                        $pay = "P";

                         $times_table[$i][$j]= $pay ;
                    }
                    else{
                        $int = "I";

                         $times_table[$i][$j]= $int ;
                    }
           }

      }

 }
```

Comment: Can you describe the final output of your multidimensionnal array that you wish for ?

Comment: @jiboulex I think they want "headings instead of numbers" which they have included the proposed output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){

             for($j = 0; $j <= 4; $j++){

               if ($j == 0){

                $times_table[$i]['Version']=  "Version 5" ;
            }
                else if ($j == 1){
                $cur_date = date("M-y", $currentdate);

                $currentdate = strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate);

                $times_table[$i]['Date']= "<strong>" . $cur_date . "</strong>" ;


                }
                else{
                    $times_table[$i]['Name']=  "gary" ;
                }
                if ($j == 3) {
                    $numbers = mt_rand(1, 100);
                    $times_table[$i]['RandNum']= $numbers ;

                }
                if ($j == 4){

                    if($i == 0 || $i == 3)
                    {
                        $pay = "P";

                    $times_table[$i]['Letter']= $pay ;
                    }
                    else{
                        $int = "I";

                    $times_table[$i]['Letter']= $int ;

                    }
                }

            }

            }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. touché

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your second for loop is not needed. You should know that you can create associative arrays like this :

```
<?php
$times_table = [];
$times_tables[] = [
    'Version' => 'Version 5',
    'Date' => 'Feb-16',
    'Name' => 'gary',
    'RandNum' => '80',
    'Letter' => 'P',
];
```

To match with your code :

```
<?php
$times_table = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
    $times_table[$i]['Version']=  "Version 5" ;
    $cur_date = date("M-y", $currentdate);
    $currentdate = strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate);
    $times_table[$i]['Date']= "<strong>" . $cur_date . "</strong>" ;
    $times_table[$i]['Name']=  "gary" ;
    $numbers = mt_rand(1, 100);
    $times_table[$i]['RandNum']= $numbers ;
    switch ($i) {
        case 0:
        case 3:
            $letter = 'P';
        break;
        default:
            $letter = 'I';
    }
    $times_table[$i]['Letter']= $letter;
}
```

I think this should do what you want in a cleaner way !

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could I ask why the keys aren't in the first array. And why create the second array $times_tables

Comment: there is one and only array : $times_table, which is multidimensional

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){

             for($j = 0; $j <= 4; $j++){

               if ($j == 0){

                $times_table["Version"][$j]=  "Version 5" ;
            }
                else if ($j == 1){
                $cur_date = date("M-y", $currentdate);

                $currentdate = strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate);

                $times_table["Date"][$j]= "<strong>" . $cur_date . "</strong>" ;


                }
                else{
                    $times_table["Name"][$j]=  "gary" ;
                }
                if ($j == 3) {
                    $numbers = mt_rand(1, 100);
                    $times_table["RandNum"][$j]= $numbers ;

                }
                if ($j == 4){

                    if($i == 0 || $i == 3)
                    {
                        $pay = "P";

                    $times_table["Letter"][$j]= $pay ;
                    }
                    else{
                        $int = "I";

                    $times_table["Letter"][$j]= $int ;

                    }
                }

            }

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create associative array like this:

```
$a=array("Version"=> "Version 5",
         "Date"=> "Feb-16",
         "Name" => "gary",
         "RandNum" => 80,
         "Letter" => "P"
        )
```

To access this array in for loop use `$a['key']`. For eg. to access version5, use `$a['version']`, to access Feb-16 use `$a['Date']`.